# Constructor not being called in class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating a helper in .net core 2.2 for caching into Redis.  When I call the Add method It doesn't go through my constructor to create the `IDistributedCache` instance.

```
public class Cache
{
    public static IDistributedCache _cache;
    public Cache(IDistributedCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }
    public static void Add(string key, byte[] value, int expiration)
    {
        var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
            .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiration));
        _cache.Set(key, value, options);
    }
}
```

I'm not understanding exactly what I am missing.  I call the method as such

```
Cache.Add("time", encodedCurrentTimeUTC, expiration);
```

EDIT:
I've removed the static entries

```
public class Cache
{
    public IDistributedCache _cache;
    public Cache(IDistributedCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }
    public void Add(string key, byte[] value, int expiration)
    {
        var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
            .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiration));
        _cache.Set(key, value, options);
    }
}
```

But when I try to call the method

```
var newItem = new Cache();
newItem.Add("time", encodedCurrentTimeUTC, expiration);
```

It tells me that I am not passing a parameter into the cache constructor.

Comment: Your `Add` method is static, so I wouldn't think your constructor would be called.

Comment: you aren't calling `new Cache`

Comment: @User the problem is a static constructor can't contain parameters - where would they come from?

Comment: @User Are you really sure that a static constructor is appropriate? Static classes should often be avoided. It'd be better to use a single instance of this class, and then register a single instance with the IoC container.

Comment: @User Well if you're going to suggest ways to fix things, probably better to put some thought into them first. If you're not sure it's a good idea, then let someone else assist.

Comment: You can't call `new Cache()`, you need to pass an implementation of `IDistributedCache` to the constructor.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Isn't the implementation already in the constructor?

Comment: @User Yes, I can see they are using static methods and I can tell they may not be aware of static constructors. That doesn't make them the right tool for the job. It's very likely the wrong tool for the job. Thus, you shouldn't go recommending it.

Comment: @TheDizzle no `IDistributedCache` is the required type, but you need to pass an instance when instantiating the object e.g. `new Cache(aDistributedCacheInstance)`. Are you using dependency injection? It would appear so looking at your code; if so you need to let the DI framework handle the instantiating for you.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I am using DI, but not sure how to get it from the DI framework.

Comment: You whole code is confusing. You have a class "Cache" with a private field "_cache". That is confusing naming of the highest order. You created a constructor that you **said** would get a specific argument, only to then wonder that it demanded that argument. It seems like you got on the wrong turn long ago. And now have walked a few miles along that path. Go back a few steps and tell us what Problem you tried to solve with this class. There is propably a beter way.

Comment: Funny that no one has asked *why* you're doing this. ASP.NET Core includes a Redis implementation of `IDistributedCache` out of the box. Just inject `IDistributedCache` where you need to cache things, and then setup the Redis provider in your Startup.cs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2#distributed-redis-cache

Comment: @ChrisPratt i'm trying to make it easier to add things to cache

Comment: Just add an extension method to `IDistributedCache` in that case. Creating a whole wrapper around `IDistributedCache` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using DI, avoid using `new` altogether.
Have your class `Cache` implement an interface such as:

```
public interface ICache
{
    void Add(string key, byte[] value, int expiration);
}

public class Cache : ICache
{
    public IDistributedCache _cache;
    public Cache(IDistributedCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }
    public void Add(string key, byte[] value, int expiration)
    {
        var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
            .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiration));
        _cache.Set(key, value, options);
    }
}
```

Register `Cache` as `ICache` with your container. [AutoFac](https://autofac.org/) example:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Cache>().As<ICache>();
```

Then in the class where you need to use your `Cache` object, inject it as a dependency:

```
class ClassThatNeedsACache
{
    ICache _cache;
    ClassThatNeedsACache(ICache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    void MethodThatUsesACache()
    {
        // Some other code to create your encodedCurrentTimeUTC and expiration
        _cache.Add("time", encodedCurrentTimeUTC, expiration);
    }
}
```

Dependency injection frameworks wire everything together in your composition root e.g. Global.asax in ASP.NET, and maintain the creation and lifetime of objects in your app.

Comment: @TheDizzle "avoid using `new` altogether" is excellent advice. [This video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) goes into depth about why that's a good idea.

Comment: Perfect solution +1